# Some incomprehensible words of James Brown – Funky President

Tags: lyrics

[This song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_ODghRTeyQ) keep playing in my mind since the time when I played some game where this song was.

Lyric web sites say different versions. I gather up all the versions in one. Cold anyone please clarify or make possible suggestions to those incomprehensible lines?

```
Funky town, nasty
Hey, listen to the man
[Incomprehensible](I'm/Rap) Godfather
Payback
Cold blooded

People, people, we've got to get over
Before we go under, Lord
People, people, we've got to get over
Before we go under

Hey, country
You didn't say what you meant
You just changed
Brand new funky President

Stock market goin' up, jobs are goin' down
And ain't no funking jobs to be found
Taxes keep goin' up, I changed from a glass
Now I drink from a paper cup, gettin' bad

People, people, we've got to get over
Before we go under

Listen to me, let's get together and raise
Let's get together, get some land
Raise our food like the man
Save our money like the Mob
Put up [Incomprehensible] on/own the job

Tell 'em, Godfather
Hello
Hey Lord, hey,

Turn on your funk motor
Get down and praise the Lord
Get sexy, sexy
Get funky and dance

Love me, baby, love me nice
Don't make it once
But can you make it twice?
I like it

People, people, we've got to get over
Before we go under
People, people, well, well, well
Before we go under

Turn on your funk motor
I know it's tough
Turn on your funk motor
Until you get enough, yeah

Hey, give yourself a
Chance to come through
Tell yourself, I can
Do what you can do

Hey, listen to the man
[Incomprehensible](I'm/Rap) Godfather
Payback
Cold blooded

People, people
People, people
Hey, people, people
Don't you see what's goin' on?

People, people, we got to get together
Get on the your good foot, huh, change it, yeah
Got to get together and get some land
Raise our food just like the man
Hey, hey, hey, hey, hey

I got to say it again
We got to get together, buy some land
Raise our food just like the man
Save our money, do like the Mob
Put up your [Incomprehensible] and own/on the job

We gotta get over
Before we go under
Time ain't a jaunt, Lord

Country, do you know
Just what I meant?
We just changed
We've got a brand new funky President

I need to be the Mayor
So I can change the things around here
I need to be the Governor
I need to be the Governor
I need to be the Governor
```

PS: I'm not native English speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Incomprehensible Godfather

The incomprehensible word is "rap", used here as an exhortation for the Godfather [Brown] to speak.

> Put up [Incomprehensible] on/own the job

The phrase is "Put up your factory, own the job," as in start your own business rather than seek employment from others.